# Scratch Org Site Domain

Tags: salesforcedx, force.com-sites, site.com, scratch-org

We've got a public Site.com in our org. When converting and migrating from MDAPI to DX, I noticed even though all the components related to the site were converted and deployed, we still have to go and manually register a Salesforce Site Domain for each of the scratch orgs before we can use the public Site.

Is there a way to automate this as part of the scratch org definition? Reading through the docs nothing stands out.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like 4 things are required in the scratch org config in order to avoid this issue and get the domain automatically registered.

```
{
  "orgName": "test org",
  "edition": "Developer",
  "features": [
    "Communities",
    "Sites",
    "SiteDotCom"
  ],
  "settings": {
    "orgPreferenceSettings": {
      "networksEnabled": true
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: For some reason, this doesn't work with Enterprise edition. Not sure why - will pursue this with Wade.

Comment: Good to know. Please let me know the outcome and I'll update my answer