# Custom domains aren't allowed in scratch orgs

Tags: salesforcedx, scratch-org, experience-cloud, custom-domain, scratch-org-definition-file

I am currently working ISV project which helps Salesforce Customer in the issuance and renewal of CA Signed Certificates, be it with Let's Encrypt or any ACME-compliant CA.

Standard flow of issuance of a CA Signed certificate is as Follow :

- Create a certificate in your org
- Download CSR
- Send it somehow to your CA
- Upload certificate
- Repeat each year or have your users complain about a red padlock

On other plateforms, this is usually solved by Certbot (or any ACME client). No such luck on Salesforce and i aim to fill that gap.

ACME protocol incurs the verification of a certificate identifier (aka domain) ownership by the CA customer.
One of the method is by checking a given file content hosted on a server servicing said domain.

Developing the product, i would like to simulate the actions a customer would take, IE, putting that file in their Experience Cloud site as a static resource with the proper redirect, the problem can be solved.

How ever, within a scratch org, when i attempt to create a custom domain, like any customer would do in their production org, in enconter the following error :

`Custom domains aren't allowed in scratch orgs, so you can't add [a domain I own]`

Is there any Scratch org feature or setting that may enable this ?

This is the Scratch org def file I currently use.

```
{
  "orgName": "gaelmotte company",
  "edition": "Enterprise",
  "language": "en_US",
  "features": [
    "EnableSetPasswordInApi",
    "Communities",
    "Sites",
    "DebugApex"
  ],
  "settings": {
    "CommunitiesSettings": {
      "enableNetworksEnabled": true
    },
    "lightningExperienceSettings": {
      "enableS1DesktopEnabled": true
    },
    "mobileSettings": {
      "enableS1EncryptedStoragePref2": false
    }
  }
}
```

As a workaround, i am considering using orgShapes, but buying a licence just to define a custom domain i may use in my tests when developing the products seems a bit excessive.

Alternatively, i could simulate issuance of certicate for the standard url of the Experience Site (`sitename.my.site.com`), but i could not prove :

- Certificate works for said url since i could not deploy it and serve HTTPS content with it
- The whole flow, ie, when a subscriber of my ISV product would use it for their Experience site on a custom domain.

Disclaimer :
i am aware Salesforce recommends using their CDN for Experience Sites, which solves the certifcate issuance and renewal.
It does not however solve every use case (should a customer require to use their OWN CA instead of let's encrypt, yet do noy OWN a CDN, or having issues with akamai cdn for instance)

Thanks for your help on this one :)
Cheers

Comment: Hi, and welcome to SFSE! Please take a moment to read about [ask] and take our quick [tour]. As written, this is a bit of an [X-Y Problem](https://xyproblem.info/). We don't know why you're trying to add a custom domain, so we can't offer, for example, potential workarounds to the problem you're having. You can [edit] your question to include more information.

Comment: thanks @sfdcfox.
Post reworked with much more details :)

Comment: only question referencing the same issue or close-ish seems to be https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/252858/scratch-org-site-domain
It does not provide an answer as to how it was solved, based on comments on the response

Comment: As a data point or points on your product idea - we have lots of customers on Exp Cloud, many of them with custom domains. Not a single one of them have issues you're describing. Perhaps they're all special and very sophisticated with lots of IT staff, right? Some of them are, many aren't.

Comment: @identigral thanks for the free user research :) 
This is mainly a hobby project, that then lead me to the discovery of the salesforce CDN, which was not a known feature within my consulting firm, for lack a experience cloud projects since akamai CDN is GA.
Having no feedback, i pursue my goal, or just for the fun of it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a call with Salesforce support for the case i oppened, it turns out they  simply do not support this due to the short lived nature of scratch orgs and have no plans to.

They suggested I resort to orgShapes instead.